# Recording using multiple lavalier mics

Tags: microphone, recording, lavalier

I have an interview-style recording to do that involves multiple people. I suppose using lavalier mics would be ideal for this. I couldn't find a way to properly record audio from more than one lavalier mics. Based on what I know, I need three different recording equipment for three lavs. The other option that I've discovered is to use an audio splitter, but I don't know how this will affect quality. Also, how I can I handle more than two lavs?

Recording separately seems redundant. Not to mention the hassle of combining the audio together in post-production. There must be some way to do this reliably.

Also, I'm on a tight budget.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 3 different sets of recording equipment.

All you need is a mixer and a recorder. The mixer allows you to take inputs of varying impedances and levels, balance them, and pass to the recorder. Don't use audio splitters, as they will not impedance match and will cause degradation of signal.

4 track mixers are really cheap these days.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my thinking, which considers "I'm on a tight budget" the #1 concern.

True, lavaliers are standard for this type of work. But if you are on such a tight budget that you don't have a mixer, my suggestion is not to use lavaliers. Especially wired lavaliers if the cable run is going to be more than 25', unless you're using very expensive cable.

Instead, use a single microphone. This was standard practice for nearly 100 years, if it worked fine for major broadcasters in the 1965, it should work ok for you. take the recording somewhere indoors with a lot of carpets and padded furniture. Scootch all the interviewees into a tight circle. Then hang blankets behind them. Consider hanging one single Sony ECM-DS70P stereo microphone from its own cable in the center of the circle of people, from a coathanger hanging above them. Place the microphone at the same height as the heads of the speakers. This is a good mic you can find on ebay for $10.

At the top of the same coat hanger, clip a Zoom F1-LP to the coathanger, plug the Sony microphone into the Zoom. Set at 96 kHz/24 bit, make sure the limiters are turned on,, and you've got a "close-enough" to broadcast quality recording for ~$180 USD.

Comment: Thanks! That's good advice I suppose.

Comment: A question though. Can I use a low-impedence dynamic mic with the Zoom F1?

Comment: Go ahead and try it. You'll probably hear something. If it doesn't sound good, or the levels are low, consider purchasing an in-line or "barrel" impedance matching transformer with your connectors of choice. Most microphone front ends only have "high" or "low-Z" so the transformer is relatively simple and inexpensive.